# ¿Cómo realizar una acción en todas las tablas de una base de datos que contenga un campo especifico?

Tags: sql-server, bucles, cursor

Tengo una Base de datos, en la que necesito limpiar los espacios de un campo en concreto en todas las tablas de la base de datos.
Este campo se llama delegado en su tabla e **idDelegado** en sus foráneas.
Por ejemplo, si el código de un delegado es `'   DEL012 '` necesito hacer un `Trim()` en todas las tablas donde haya un **`idDelegado`**.
para consultar todas las tablas donde tenga un **`iDdelegado`** lo hago tal que así:

```
Select TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'idDelegado' AND TABLE_NAME NOT like 'VIS_%'
ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME
```

Y se me ocurre recorrer el resultado de la consulta con un cursor y hacer el Trim() correspondiente, pero dudo que esta sea la mejor solución.
¿Hay alguna forma mejor de hacerlo?

Comment: De hecho, lo que propones es la mejor opción porque de cualquier forma tienes que hacer un UPDATE por cada tabla. Si necesitas hacerlo más eficiente o robusto, hay opciones adicionales que se pueden agregar al proceso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma adecuada para este tipo de trabajo, que a la vez es mas sencilla que armar un ciclo con cursores, es construir un "factory query", es decir una consulta que construye otra consulta, por ejemplo:

```
Select  'UPDATE ' + '[' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '].[' + TABLE_NAME + 
        '] SET ' + COLUMN_NAME + ' = RTRIM(LTRIM(' + COLUMN_NAME + '))'
        from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'idDelegado' 
            AND TABLE_NAME NOT like 'VIS_%'
        ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME
```

Lo que harías luego de ejecutarla, sería copiar los resultados en otra consulta y ejecutarla.

El único problema que tienes, es que parece ser que estamos hablando de una columna `ID` por lo que la modificación puede ser complicada, particularmente si es `FK` en algunas tablas, en el mejor escenario, deberás plantear un orden de actualización comenzando con las tablas detalle y luego las maestras.